# Unity Leap Motion - palm position changes with head rotation in VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, leap-motion

I'm trying to use the palm position to get the hands distance from the sensors origin (surface) which is then used in a function I wrote that compares the position within a set of bounds (one for each axis) to calculate a weight for the data from the sensor as the 'confidence' variable built into the leap API is terrible.

The problem is that whenever I turn my head the axis seems to change which is completely throwing out my ranges. Is there a way I can neutralize the rotation so that the axis is consistent, i.e. Z is away from the sensor, X left and right and Y up and down. If I face forwards it works perfectly as the axis are as detailed but if I look right, it's gone. :(

I would appreciate any help.

FYI - the parameter 'position' passed in is the hand's palm position.

```
 float CalculateSensorWeight(Vector position)
    {
        float HighestX = 1f, LowestX = -1f;
        float HighestY = 1.2f, LowestY = 0.6f;
        float HighestZ = 1f, LowestZ = 0.4f;

        HighestX *= transform.root.lossyScale.x;
        LowestX *= transform.root.lossyScale.x;
        HighestY *= transform.root.lossyScale.x;
        LowestY *= transform.root.lossyScale.x;
        HighestZ *= transform.root.lossyScale.x;
        LowestZ *= transform.root.lossyScale.x;

        Debug.Log(position);

        clampedX = (1f - (-1f)) / (HighestX - LowestX) * (position.ToVector3().x - HighestX) + 1f;
        clampedY = (1f - (-1f)) / (HighestY - LowestY) * (position.ToVector3().y - HighestY) + 1f;
        clampedZ = (1f - (-1f)) / (HighestZ - LowestZ) * (position.ToVector3().z - HighestZ) + 1f;

        totalClamp = clampedX + clampedY + clampedZ;

        //Debug.Log(clampedX + " , " + clampedY + " , " + clampedZ + " = " + totalClamp);

        float weight = (1f - 0f) / (3f - (-3f)) * (totalClamp - 3f) + 1f;
        weight = ((weight-0f)/(1f-0f))*(1f-(-1f))+(-1f);
        weight = 1f - Mathf.Abs(weight);

        //Debug.Log("Weight = " + weight);
        //Round the weight to 2 decimal places for asthetics and ease
        weight = Round(weight, 2);
        return weight;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved this by using transform.inversetransformpoint and just adjusting my threshold values accordingly